# Is there any software which displays geotagging plus compass data visualizations?

Tags: software, geotagging, gps, visualization

I was eyeing Pentax's new [GPS hotshoe accessory](http://www.pentaximaging.com/accessories/GPS_Unit) for geotagging photos and noticed it also includes a digital compass and will record the camera direction as well as latitude & longitude.

That got me wondering — if you combine the lat/long, compass bearing and lens focal length, you'd have a pretty good sense of the camera's position and field of view.

Obviously many photo organization programs will let you plot your photo locations on a map, but I would like a way to visualize more data, perhaps generating plots like [this wikipedia diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Nationalmuseum-karta.png). Is there any software that displays this data?

Comment: Not an answer, but http://www.quora.com/Which-geo-tagging-photo-sites-use-embedded-GPS-compass-data has a similar question with no good solutions.

Comment: This seems to me to be a survey - you're asking 'is there anything interesting'.

Comment: @rfusca: Good comment, I edited the question to be more specific. I really am looking for an answer, not a discussion.

Comment: Once a few more camera vendors will implemented the compass data visualizations feature the DAM vendors will add this feature on their products (including us, on [Daminion Software](http://daminion.net) :)

Comment: I guess my question is, outside of phone cameras on phones that actually have a compass...are compasses an integrated feature of many (or any) dedicated camera systems? Until compasses are an ubiquitous feature, I don't foresee any major photo management software packages implementing compass support. That makes this question pretty speculative, and therefor off topic.

Comment: @jrista: Well the reason I asked was because I noticed it as a feature of Pentax's new GPS accessory, which is only compatible with their SLR and medium-format cameras--not exactly camera phones. Also, while many smartphones do have a compass for navigation, I'm not aware of them embedding the camera bearing in the EXIF data. I'm not suggesting that this is a "ubiquitous" feature, but it's clearly not speculative.

Answer (score 4):

I have not tried this, but it appears that [GeoSetter](http://www.geosetter.de/en/) supports visualizing the heading data from GPS data if the GPS device recorded it. Optionally, you could add this data manually after the fact.

From the [change log](http://www.geosetter.de/en/changes/):

> Optional synchronizing of heading data when synchronizing with GPS
>   track files

More notes and some [screenshots](http://www.geosetter.de/mantis/file_download.php?file_id=40&type=bug) for the feature are available on GeoSetter's Bug Tracker [here](http://www.geosetter.de/mantis/view.php?id=82).

Answer (score 0):

I know it is possible to visualise that kind of data using Google Earth and KML-files. I'm not sure if there is any programs that will convert EXIF-tags into KML-files, but it shouldn't be too hard if you know a bit of programming.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cheap way to do it with iphone using the $3 [Theodolite](http://hunter.pairsite.com/theodolite/) app that records the bearing, vertical and horizontal angle, as well as the position. However, you would then have to export this metadata to another program to be able to do more interesting stuff with it.